# Where is the shared folder of host machine?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, filemanager

I have installed Ubuntu as virtual machine under Mac, by VMware Fusion.

I have already configured VMware Fusion to share a disk of Mac...

But I still can't see the disk in the file manager...

Should I do something to mount the disk?

Comment: is the Mac not available under the directory /mnt/hgfs ?  From a terminal ls /mnt/hgfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gary suggested in his comment to your question, the default for VMware appears to be mounting shared folders in the directory `/mnt/hgfs`.

You can list the folders in that directory with `ls /mnt/hgfs` in a terminal window.

If you want to use Nautilus, the default Ubuntu GUI file manager/explorer, then after you open it press <kbd>ctrl+L</kbd> and enter the path `/mnt/hgfs` into the `Location` box and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.